# Why aren't the numpy matrices equal?

Tags: python, numpy

Why does this return False?

```
temp = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

filter_indices = range(3)[1:2]
filter_indices2 = range(3)[1:]

print np.array_equal(temp[1:2,1:], temp[filter_indices, filter_indices2])
```

but these are equal:

```
np.array_equal(temp[1:2,1:], temp[filter_indices, 1:])
```

It looks like they'd be the same to me, but it seems like this second array is filtering differently than the first.

Comment: `temp[1:2,1:].shape = (1, 2)`, so try `temp[[filter_indices], [filter_indices2]]`.

Comment: Awesome, why does that work though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately it is the product of your first slice, as there is a difference between indexing with `slice(1, 2)` and `[1]`.  By indexing with `1:2`, you produce

```
> temp[1:2]
array([[4, 5, 6]])
```

which has shape `(1, 3)`, i.e. a row vector (1 row, 3 cols). Using `filter_indices`, you are producing essentially

```
> temp[1] #equivalent to temp[filter_indices]
array([4, 5, 6])
```

with shape `(3,)`. To get the same behavior, index with

```
> temp[[1]] #equivalent to temp[[filter_indices]]
array([[4, 5, 6]])
```